# Apply css rule for specific media query and consider remaining rules for all other media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have got interesting question with media queries.

Example as below:

```
.card {
 padding: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 300px;
 border: 1px solid red;
    **--- 1st media query**
   @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 
        1360px) and (max-height: 768px) { 
          padding: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 15px;
   }
   @media only screen and (min-width: 1660px) { 
     /* Here I am not going to mention the rule for padding - but 
       wanted */
        margin-bottom: 15px;
   }
}
```

Expected :

1. So media query runs for screens between 1024 to 1360 and override the padding and margin-bottom rules
2. After that for bigger screen more than 1660px the margin-bottom rule is going to applied but the padding bottom is still from the previous media query but not from default card class css rule

How to make sure the "padding:25px" rule is applied to all screens except the first media query.

Comment: Media queries should only be used for overwriting the properties you want to - if you do not want to overwrite a property, then just leave it out of your media query and it will inherit from the original class

Comment: I agree with you @Pete. But the problem I have there is the padding which is overridden applied to all the screens after 1360 break point as well. So only we way have now is introduce another breakpoint to apply default css rule?

Comment: Ah right, you do not show that in your media queries - you only show the padding in a query that has all limits set.  In that case, you would apply the original in the next media query up to reset it for the rest of the screen sizes